# Inboard or Outboard

Tags: equipment, in-the-box

Quick survey:

How many tools do you use in the box and how many are actual pieces of rack gear?

What type of mixboard do you have and do you still use volume/pan automation on it?

I'm curious to what you use.

Answer (score 1):

I did a huge outboard-box purge in 2004: compressors, limiters, tube pre's, DAT machine, the whole lot. I went entirely virtual except a single [Waldorf Pulse+](http://www.vintagesynth.com/waldorf/pulse.php) analog synth and - ONLY for nostalgia - a single [Electric Mistress](http://www.ehx.com/products/deluxe-electric-mistress) flanger pedal/box. Now I'm finding that I still collect hardware, but smaller sound-making objects ([Thingamagoops](http://bleeplabs.com/thingamagoop2/), [Stylophones](http://www.thinkgeek.com/electronics/musical-instruments/aa64/), and other objects/toys) and real instruments, usually percussive (chimes, cymbals, drums, etc.).

I think this is all because emulation, automation, and delivery made virtualization far more attractive from a workflow, space, heat, power, and clutter perspective, as well as a personal shift from synthesized sound to re-synthesized recorded sound (I still do both, but the latter has been my recent focus).

I could see buying a [Moogerfooger](http://www.moogmusic.com/moogerfooger/) or five, though. :-D

Comment: Wow, cool. Fan of the mini-moog?

Comment: And what Tube Pres did you have??? Wish I would have known you... That's all I use to record in my studio.

Comment: The first analog synth I ever used was actually an original Mini Moog! In terms of tube pre's, nothing special, mostly for guitar warming. Sheesh, not sure I can even remember now, old age is catching up with me..! :-) Nothing earthshatteringly nifty, though. Couldn't afford much back then!

Answer (score 1):

My outboard gear consists of a mic preamp and my collection of analog and modular synths. Everything else is in the box.

Answer (score 1):

I have an Focusrite Octopre,and the 8 channel mic pre for Pro Tools HD.  I also have a Rane 6 channel headphone amp and a Rane 8 channel mixer.  Apart from the Command 8 and the Novation keyboard everything else is either A/D converters or MIDI routing.

I like everything to be in the box.  You can waste so much time with analogue gear, especially sorting out tuning and earth problems.